# TwitchIO: Delete a single message in channel

Tags: python-3.x, twitch-api

How can I delete a single message sent by a user using TwitchIO?

```py
@bot.event
async def event_message(ctx):
    await ctx.content.delete() # Does not work
    await ctx.content.remove() # Does not work
    await ctx.channel.timeout(ctx.author, 1) # Does not work
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is older, but I'll answer it anyway.
Twitchio doesn't directly support this.
But you can delete individual messages in Twitch Chat, see the Twitch IRC documentation.
[CLEARMSG (Twitch Commands)](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/irc/commands#clearmsg-twitch-commands)
You need the message ID for this. You get the ID in the message tags.
[Message tags](https://twitchio.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/twitchio.html#twitchio.dataclasses.Message.tags)
Code example:

```
async def event_message(message):
    if not message.author.name == self.bot.nick:
        message_id = message.tags['id']
        await message.channel.send(f"/delete {message_id}")
```

If you want to timeout someone, do the following:

```
await message.channel.timeout(message.author.name, 120, f"reason")
```

Twitchio documentation [Channel.timeout](https://twitchio.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/twitchio.html#twitchio.dataclasses.Channel.timeout)